# Count inversions in nlogn

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

Consider an array 'a'. Two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j.

For example, given

```
int a[5] = {2, 3, 8, 6, 1}
```

This has 5 "inverses":

```
(8,6) (2,1) (3,1) (8,1) (6,1)
```

My assignment is to write a C++ program to count the number of "inverse" pairs in array, with running time scaling as O(*n* log*n*)

My code has running time as O(*n*²):

```
int nghichdao(int a[], int n)
{
    int d = 0;
    for (int j = 1;j < n;j++)
        for (int i = 0;i < j;i++)
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                d++;
                cout << "(" << a[i] << "," << a[j] << ")" << endl;
            }
    return d;
}
```

How can I improve this to O(*n* log*n*)?

Comment: Did you try anything already? Asking for _"Any ideas?"_ sounds too broad to be asked here. This may turn into an endless discussion which is what we don't want here. The site is rather about concise FAQ like question and answer pairs. You also may want to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Sorry about thay because this i my first time i ask. i already write code but running time is O(n^2)

Comment: Hint: If you don't iterate over those indices for which `i < j` is false then you get `n * log n`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Merge sort to achieve inversion count in N*logN. Refer this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/